# Wrapper to write to multiple streams

Tags: python, file-io

In python, is there an easy way to set up a file-like object for writing that is actually backed by multiple output streams? For instance, I want something like this:

```
file1 = open("file1.txt", "w")
file2 = open("file2.txt", "w")
ostream = OStreamWrapper(file1, file2, sys.stdout)

#Write to both files and stdout at once:
ostream.write("ECHO!")
```

So what I'm looking for is `OStreamWrapper`. I know it'd be pretty easy to write my own, but if there's an existing one, I'd rather use that and not have to worry about finding and covering edge cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Way to wrap all public `file` functions:

```
import sys

def _call_for_all_streams(func_name):
    def wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
        result = []
        for stream in self._streams:
            func = getattr(stream, func_name)
            result.append(func(*args, **kwargs))
        return result
    return wrapper

class OStreamWrapper(object):
    def __init__(self, *streams):
        self._streams = streams

for method in filter(lambda x: not x.startswith('_'), dir(file)):
    setattr(OStreamWrapper, method, _call_for_all_streams(method))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    file1 = open("file1.txt", "w")
    file2 = open("file2.txt", "w")
    ostream = OStreamWrapper(file1, file2, sys.stdout)
    ostream.write("ECHO!")
    ostream.close()
```

But it's kinda dirty.

Comment: Note that this solution closes all the files passed to `OStreamWrapper` when you `close()` it. It will cause troubles if you want to continue writing to this files after the operation (e.g. one of the files is `sys.stdout`).

Answer (score 4):

```
class OStreamWrapper(object):

    def __init__(self, *streams):
        self.streams = list(streams)

    def write(self, string):
        for stream in self.streams:
            stream.write(string)

    def writelines(self, lines):
        # If you want to use stream.writelines(), you have
        # to convert lines into a list/tuple as it could be
        # a generator.
        for line in lines:
            for stream in self.streams:
                stream.write(line)

    def flush(self):
        for stream in self.streams:
            stream.flush()
```

Comment: Thanks. I know how to write it myself, but like I said, I'd rather not because there's more to the file interface than that. There's also `writelines`, `flush`, `truncate`, `close`, `tell`, `seek`, etc. Yes it's fairly easy to write, but not as easy to get 100% correct. Plus it's something that comes up a lot, so what I'm hoping for is a standard class or some kind of trick that I can use so I don't have to rewrite it every time, or make it a shared module that I have to keep track of. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @АндрейБеньковский Updated

Comment: The `writelines` function as written isn't quite correct (it doesn't write a trailing `\n` after each line, instead calling `write` directly)

Answer (score 0):

[Logbook](http://packages.python.org/Logbook/) is another option although it is more than that. Its handlers are more powerful and you can combine whatever you like.

Comment: Why would I use this over the standard library [logging](http://docs.python.org/library/logging.html) module? In this particular case I would think it is best just to use standard library features.